# What is an openFileDescriptor mode?

Tags: android, kotlin

Why are there fileDescriptor modes (r,w,rw) and what are they for?

```
   contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "w")
```

They are described in the documention like this:

> If opening with the exclusive "r" or "w" modes, the returned ParcelFileDescriptor could be a pipe or socket pair to enable streaming of data. Opening with the "rw" mode implies a file on disk that supports seeking. If possible, always use an exclusive mode to give the underlying ContentProvider the most flexibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are nothing but `modes` in which you can open file descriptor.

- `"r"` Read only mode. cannot be used for writing
- `"w"` Write only mode. cannot be used for reading.
- `"rw"` for read-and-write.
- `"rwt"` for truncating or overwriting existing file contents.